# Android Studio Flutter auto-suggestion does not show up for override methods

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am not able to override initState() or any other methods by simply typing its name and waiting for auto-suggestion.
The IDE just says No suggestions (first image), but Ctrl + O does the job normally (2nd image).

[image]

[image]

I tried flutter clear, flutter pub get, upgrade flutter, dart, plugins... also turning off Power Save Mode, Invalidate caches... but the problem is still not solved.

Please tell me a way to do this just by typing the methods name, without opening the "Choose Methods to Override menu" and then clicking to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Flutter 3.0.0 and fixed in Flutter version 3.0.2:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#302-june-10-2022

But there is still a suggestion bug for `setState` method:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49233

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, tried all day just to figure out the solution and i found that the problem is with the android studio, reverting it back to flutter version 2.10.5 solve the problem.

VS code work well with flutter v3.0 but i am more comfortable working with AS, so until AS update/fix the problem i will stick with the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is not generate Properly so try to create with type st and  select option from tips menu and then write your class name then it should work.flutter clean also work in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am giving up, start to think it is a feature, not an issue

Answer (score 0):

i have try all above solution and i have flutter 3.10.6 but non of work

> Remove flutter, dart and other snippets package from android studio

> from file->invalid cache-> restart

> reinstall all plugins.

Now it's working properly